# Stopped process doesn't continue to work after sending SIGCONT

Tags: linux, bash, signal

I start `cat` in terminal:

```
$ cat
```

Then in second terminal I send stop signal:

```
$ kill -SIGSTOP $(pgrep cat)
```

And that works - `cat` is stopped. Now I want to wake up this `cat` process by sending `SIGCONT`:

```
$ kill -SIGCONT $(pgrep cat)
```

And nothing happens. However if I use `fg` in first shell then `cat` will be woken up. Why `SIGCONT` doesn't continue `cat` execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitting "ctrl-Z" in the shell suspends the current foreground process, by sending it a `STOP` signal. This (I believe) also results in the process's standard input being detached from the shell - it is now a background process.

The `bg` command sends a `CONTINUE` signal to the command, but does not reconnect its standard input to the shell. Since cat is waiting on the standard input, it stays stopped. As you mentioned, the `fg` command does indeed connect the standard input back yo the shell.

When you send a `STOP` signal to your process, the shell is notified via a CHILD signal and puts it in the background and the same thing happens.

You can see the difference when you hit "ctrl-Z":

```
[1]  + 8336 suspended  cat
```

And when you send a `STOP` signal manually:

```
[1]  + 8336 suspended (signal)  cat
```